# Insufficient Permission Error with Google Sheets/Drive API: "Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided"

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to control a google sheet with python, but am getting the above error. I have used the google drive/sheet APIs, which send me an email saying "address not found" because the domain I set up with the API doesn't exit even though I set it up on the google cloud console website.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("NewAutoTraderTracker2-4be0a80b8029.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("AutoTraderTracker2").sheet1
```

The error is coming from `sheet = client.open("AutoTraderTracker2).sheet1`
I followed a tutorial by Tech With Tim called "Python Google Sheets API Tutorial"

Comment: So if i understand correctly, you were not able to execute the step called "Sharing the Sheet" in the tutorial?

Comment: @Ugurite It is giving me the error on "sheet = client.open("...").sheet1" when I actually am accessing the sheet

Comment: Please see if you have access to the spreadsheet "AutoTraderTracker2" by executing this `client.list_spreadsheet_files()` just before `sheet = client.open("...").sheet1`

Comment: @Ugurite client.list_spreadsheet_files() gives the same error which  sheet = client.open("...").sheet1 did

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'" should be "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" (without the ' at the end).

For the the email error unselect "Notify People" when sharing the google sheets with your service account.